# Correct verbs in sentence

Tags: verb-agreement

Assume that I am advertising that a payment will be asked only if we actually execute a given job right, and I say:

> "if we don't do it right, we have been working for free"
>
> "if we won't do it right, we have been working for free"
>
> "if we don't do it right, we would have been working for free"

Can you tell me what is the most effective and correct way to express (advertise) the idea (especially the correct choice of verbs), and are the above sentences wrong ?

Answer (score 7):

Are you *describing* how you work, or are you *advertising* your way of working? Your text says you are advertising, but your examples are all descriptive in nature.

If you are describing a current job where you know that you will be paid only if you do your job properly:

> If we don’t do it right, we will have been working for free

If on the other hand you are actually *advertising* that you only charge for work done right:

> If we don’t do it right, our work is free
>   If we don’t do it right, you don’t pay

would both be better options.

You could even make it rhyme:

> If we don’t do okay, you don’t have to pay

Comment: Yes thanks Janus. The intention was to put out an actual advertisement. In other words, the client would be asked to pay only if really satisfied. If not, our work would have been "for free" (no payment asked). Wanted it to sound like a fact. A way we work.

Comment: Janus, check the questions if they are off-topic or otherwise close-worthy before answering.

Comment: Re: "If you are describing a current job where you know that you will be paid only if you do your job properly:

If we don’t do it right, we will have been working for free" -- Can you tell me the reason why the third example ("If we don't do it right, we **would have been** working for free") in the question wouldn't be grammatical there? // I'm a non-native speaker, and such sentences where "**would** ..." is used for a imagined situation, like in the given example, seem correct to me. But I keep learning that the correct form to use is "**will** ...". But I can't understand why.

Comment: @MrReality Generally speaking, any form with _would_ in the apodosis is only possible if the verb in the protasis is backshifted (i.e., is itself some form of past construction). Wikipedia has a [simple overview of English conditionals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_sentence#English) you may find useful.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and the link; I've read about the four conditionals earlier, but I keep finding examples violating it. I've found these example sentences uttered by native speakers; can you tell me whether any or all of them are actually incorrect, and whether there's a more apt choice (All 3 seem very apt to me)?: 1) "If two members of staff happen to fall in love and decide to marry it would be churlish to be appointing blame.";  2) "If I am fortunate enough to be selected for a grant, I would be able to pay for child care." 3) "If God is omnipotent, he ...

Comment: ...would be able to prevent all of the evil."